# How to Retain the control input values between pages using jquery and mvc2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Here is my problem..

I am working jquery and mvc2.  I selected or writing the values in input controls like check box or text box or drop downs, then i moved to next page, then i get back to same page i need the check box to be checked or the text box having values..how can i do it

maintain the input control values between pages
Thank you in advance

```
    #region TableHeaderOnStart
    public string TableHeaderOnStart()
    {
        string TableHeaderValues = string.Empty;
        try
        {
        TableHeaderValues = TheadShipTo + "," + TheadCountry + "," + TheadNotes + "," + TheadShipStatus + "," + TheadStoreName + "," + TheadRSM;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TableHeaderValues = string.Empty;
            Logger.WriteToLog(Logger.LogType.Error, Constant.strmerchantname, Constant.struser, "OrderController.TableHeaderValues()", ex.Message, null, null);
        }
        return TableHeaderValues;
    }
    #endregion

    #region TableHeaders
    public void TableHeaders(bool ShipTo, bool Country, bool Notes, bool ShipStatus, bool StoreName, bool RSM)
    {
        TheadShipTo = ShipTo;
        TheadCountry = Country;
        TheadNotes = Notes;
        TheadShipStatus = ShipStatus;
        TheadStoreName = StoreName;
        TheadRSM = RSM;
    }
    #endregion
```

The above Code in parent View's Contoller page...
Below code is for Parent view.. in jquery....almost i got it....

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#thetable1').tableScroll({ height: 100 });
        $('#table').tableScroll({ height: 100 });
        $('#thetable3').tableScroll({ height: 100 });


        var Url = '<%: Url.Action("TableHeaderOnStart", "Orders") %>';
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: Url,
            data: "",
            dataType: "HTML",
            success: function (data) {

                var Header = data.split(',');

                if (Header[0] == 'True') {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Ship To')").show();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").showCol("Ship To")
                    });
                    $('#SHIPTO').attr('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Ship To')").hide();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").hideCol("Ship To")
                    });
                    $('#SHIPTO').attr('checked', false);
                }

                if (Header[1] == 'True') {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Country')").show();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").showCol("Country")
                    });
                    $('#COUNTRY').attr('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Country')").hide();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").hideCol("Country")
                    });
                    $('#COUNTRY').attr('checked', false);
                }

                if (Header[2] == 'True') {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Notes')").show();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").showCol("Notes")
                    });
                    $('#NOTES').attr('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Notes')").hide();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").hideCol("Notes")
                    });
                    $('#NOTES').attr('checked', false);
                }

                if (Header[3] == 'True') {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Ship Status')").show();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").showCol("Ship Status")
                    });
                    $('#SHIPSTATUS').attr('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Ship Status')").hide();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").hideCol("Ship Status")
                    });
                    $('#SHIPSTATUS').attr('checked', false);
                }

                if (Header[4] == 'True') {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Store Name')").show();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").showCol("Store Name")
                    });
                    $('#STORENAME').attr('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('Store Name')").hide();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").hideCol("Store Name")
                    });
                    $('#STORENAME').attr('checked', false);
                }

                if (Header[5] == 'True') {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('RequestedShipMethod')").show();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").showCol("RequestedShipMethod")
                    });
                    $('#RSM').attr('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#jqTable tr').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td:contains('RequestedShipMethod')").hide();
                        jQuery("#jqTable").hideCol("RequestedShipMethod")
                    });
                    $('#RSM').attr('checked', false);
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if (xhr.status == 403) {
                    window.location.href = '<%: Url.Action( "SessionExpire", "Home" ) %>';
                }
            }
        });

        //window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        $(window).unload(function () {
            var SHIPTO = document.getElementById('SHIPTO').checked;
            var COUNTRY = document.getElementById('COUNTRY').checked;
            var NOTES = document.getElementById('NOTES').checked;
            var SHIPSTATUS = document.getElementById('SHIPSTATUS').checked;
            var STORENAME = document.getElementById('STORENAME').checked;
            var RSM = document.getElementById('RSM').checked;

            var Url = '<%: Url.Action("TableHeaders", "Orders") %>';
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: Url,
                data: "ShipTo=" + SHIPTO + "&Country=" + COUNTRY + "&Notes=" + NOTES + "&ShipStatus=" + SHIPSTATUS + "&StoreName=" + STORENAME + "&RSM=" + RSM,
                dataType: "HTML",
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    if (xhr.status == 403) {
                        window.location.href = '<%: Url.Action( "SessionExpire", "Home" ) %>';
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: you should have a view model that stores this value and then uses values present in this model to show the check box to be checked or the text box having values etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that when you click on " Next " link on your already rendered view , you are calling an another Action Method where you render your Next View . You should be posting your Values from your parent view to Next View , store your values of Textboxes, checkboxes in a Session Variable in your Parent View's Controller action Method and then pass the control to the Next View's action method ... Render that ...

When you again call a Back Link,button on this view ..Call your Parent View's controller action Method which will render your Parent View with already present  values of textboxes , checkboxes as earlier you have stored them in Session variables...

If you can provide some code then it would be easy to help you out more

Comment: Your are right Ashes, me too tried in the same way.. i dont know where i made mistake.... i will update my code..